# best method to frequently change view inside layout

Tags: android, xml

I want to add and remove some views frequently like
Recycler view,textview,seekbar,customview,imagebutton etc.!!!!
I know following methode to perform it

1. Add all view to layout and just play with `Visibility.GONE`, `Visible` and other..
2. using layout params add and remove view...
3. Use View.inflater to add and remove predefined XML views(I'm using)

So question is

1.Is there any other method to do it?
 2.  Which one you prefer and why?

Comment: OK another way is use fragmnet according to A_J and update layout by fragment transition.

Answer (score 1):

When you make Visibility.GONE all the views and associated resources such as image, sound files will be kept in the memory and if you have a lot if resources that may slow down your application. I think better way would be to use Fragments.

Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). Hope this helped